# Strip double newlines with Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In Liquid, you can capture a variable:

```
{% capture header %}

<!-- My header content -->

{% endcapture %}
```

Then whatever is within this variable can be transformed with a filter:

```
{{ header | strip_newlines }}
```

Now, let's say you have some references/meta tags in the `<head>` on a web page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

{% if page.demo %} <link href="/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">{% endif %}
<link href="/css/hello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

How would you strip only the double newlines? What I want to end up is a clean `<head>` with one "reference" per line. The "if" structure for the demo.css file will make it so that the source of non-demo pages will look a bit like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link href="/css/hello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

I don't want that extra whitespace between the lines - in some cases, on bigger sites it can be 10+ lines of whitespace. Looking for a suggestion on how to get rid of this whitespace by filtering the content.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Jekyll plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) that strips the whitespace.

> Jekyll plugins by Aucor: Plugins for eg. trimming unwanted
>   newlines/whitespace and sorting pages by weight attribute.

You can it directly from its [Github repository](https://github.com/aucor/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/strip.rb). So basically you wrap your code with `{% strip %}{% endstrip %}`. Even if this doesn't suit you needs, you can easily change the ruby script.

For example:

```
{% strip %}
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     {% if page.demo %} <link href="/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     media="screen">{% endif %}
     <link href="/css/hello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
{% endstrip %}
```

However, please remember the nature of Jekyll plugins, you can't run them on the Github Pages server.

Quote from [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/):

```
GitHub Pages is powered by Jekyll, however all Pages sites are generated using the --safe option to disable custom plugins for security reasons. Unfortunately, this means your plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to GitHub Pages.

You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, but you'll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files.
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Liquid has [a built-in way of controlling whitespace.](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/) If your project is using Liquid 4.0 or later then you'll be able to use hyphens inside the braces to avoid creating new lines.

```
{%- capture random -%}
Here's a cool example
{%- endcapture -%}
```